# How to view dmidecode output?

Tags: linux

I wanted to use the `dmidecode` command to retrieve serial information of a remote machine (server). In sites such as [this](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-get-hardware-information-with-dmidecode-command-on-linux/) they mention "output", but when I type it into my prompt, it just stays blank. Any help would be appreciated!

```
# dmidecode -t system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're literally typing that into the terminal, nothing is happening because it's considered a comment. What they mean by the `#` is that it should be run as root. So try: `sudo dmidecode -t system`.

Comment: Thanks! It says dmidecode isn't installed on my system. Is there another way to view system information while using preinstalled commands?

Comment: Perhaps look into installing it. Otherwise, "Pre-installed commands" is arbitrary, it depends on your system/distribution. For example, it is already "pre-installed" on mine.